# how to display a modal on a selected item in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a list of services that I am getting from an api,
the values are ID, Name and NeedAuthorization, and when a service need authorization, i want to display a modal box to enter the authorization code.
 I'm trying this:

```
selectedService.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (services().NeedAuthorization == 1 && selectedService == services().ID) {
            $('#preAuthorizationModal').modal('show');
        }

    });
```

but it's not working for me. 
I'm fairly new to knockout and a lil bit of help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Step through with breakpoints.

Comment: You could use Knockout instead of jquery to present and dismiss the modal. Is that what you are asking how to do?

Comment: you're subscribing to an observable but not using it's value in the subscription's callback function... looks fishy to me

Comment: @RobertSlaney the thing is the selected service only return the ID, therefore the problem would be how to use the ID to check if the particular service with that ID requires authorization

Comment: @CrimsonChris the modal is not showing, how do you recommend calling the modal box only with knockout?

Comment: Is that line of jquery even getting run?

Answer (score 0):

Presenting and dismissing with Knockout can be done with the 'if' or 'with' binding. You could create a "ModalLayer" that is responsible for showing modals. You could communicate with this layer using signals/events/subscriptions for example.

The HTML for the ModalLayer would look something like.

```
<!-- ko with: modalViewModel -->
    <div data-bind="text: title"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: body"></div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: buttons">
        ...
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Or using components...

```
<!-- ko if: componentName -->
    <div data-bind="component: { name: componentName, params: componentParams }"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```